# Python MapServer MapScript & Mongo - Use GeoJSON String Vs File

Tags: python, mapserver, mongodb, mapscript

I have been using Python MapScript bindings for MapServer - and they work great. A new datasource for the application I am working on is MongoDB.  I have seen mentions of a MongoDB Driver for MapServer - but that won't work, as some 'data massaging' is required, that is not possible directly in Mongo.

My workflow is this:

1. Using pymongo - get data of interest from Mongo
2. 'Massage' data - save as valid geojson into tempfile
3. Mapfile layers are of type MS_OGR - and connection is set to temp geojson file from step above

Overall, this workflow works good, and is stable.  But, some of the geojson payloads are fairly big - say 75-100 MB.  And in some cases, writing geojson to the tempfiles can take a few seconds.  And then I also have to deal with cleanup...

Rather that write the geojson to tempfiles, I am hoping to just use geojson string in the mapfile layers.  But I can't get this work.

Is this even possible?  Any other suggestions?